# XML validation against DTD

Tags: xml, xml-validation, dtd

I have this XML along with an embedded DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE customers [
<!ELEMENT customers (name,age,roll,sex)>
<!ELEMENT name (#CDATA)>
<!ELEMENT age (#CDATA)>
<!ELEMENT roll (#CDATA)>
<!ELEMENT sex (#CDATA)>
]>
<customers>
<name>XYZ</name>
<age>19</age>
<roll>23</roll>
<sex>M</sex>
</customers>
```

When i try to validate the XML, its showing me an error. But if i change the #CDATA to #PCDATA then the validation is successful.

Question 1) I don't have a proper explanation why is this happening. The only difference between the two is: #CDATA will not parse whereas #PCDATA will parse. In such a case. both the validations should succeed right? Please explain where am i wrong since the output of this validation is going against my concept.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as `#CDATA` available for use in XML DTDs. It is an unknown keyword. That's why you get an error.

`CDATA` is a keyword that is used when declaring *attributes* in a DTD. You cannot declare an element to be of type `CDATA` (or `#CDATA`).

The string `CDATA` is also found in CDATA sections (`<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`), which are entirely different things. They can be used in an XML document to escape characters (such as `&`) that would otherwise be interpreted as markup. CDATA sections are not declared in the DTD; they are simply used when needed.

If you have markup such as `<name>L&T</name>` (that is not enclosed in a CDATA section), then it will be rejected by the parser. It does not matter how the `name` element is declared in the DTD.

Comment: Why will it be rejected even if i use #PCDATA in the DTD for name?

Comment: It will be rejected because markup like `<name>L&T</name>` is not well-formed. Having `#PCDATA` in the DTD does not change this.

Comment: If I use single quote ' , double quote " or greater then > symbol without any CDATA section then also will the parser reject the XML ?

Comment: `<name>L&amp;T > " '</name>` is well-formed. You don't have to escape a `>` character in element content. The characters that really require care are `&` and `<`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax.

Answer (score 1):

A CDATA section starts with `<![CDATA[` and ends with `]]>`: `<sex><![CDATA[M]]></sex>`.
This is intended to include anything your XML parser should just skip without interpreting: significant line breaks, special characters, XML markup in a role of a text string. The only thing it cannot directly contain is `]]>`.

PCDATA is *parsed* CDATA, which corresponds to usual plain text.

So PCDATA is what you really need.

Comment: Please inform if i got this correct: If i use #PCDATA and have some text like <name>L&T</name> then the XML parser will parse it to <name>L&amp;T</name> BUT if i use <name><![CDATA[L&T]]></name> then it will remain as <name>L&T</name>. Am I correct? Or, did i get it the other way? Please inform.