# Declaring multiple rules in DTD schema

Tags: xml, dtd

I have an xml file with dtd schema.
I try to add some rules on attributes and elements.
so far, I managed to have two `ATTLIST` for different elements in the following format:

```
<!DOCTYPE root [
 <!ATTLIST a ..... >
 <!ATTLIST b ..... >
]>
```

Now I wish to do the following:
assume i have:

```
<a ...><value>some_value_with_&&&</value></a>
```

of course, that value must be surrounded with `<![CDATA[some_value_with_&&&]]>`

Since I already have a dtd schema, I thought I can remove the CDATA (leaving it as it initially was) and then declare its a cdata type in the DTD, is that possible?
I tried to add the following:
`<!ELEMENT value (#CDATA)>`
but i have two issues with it:

1. It forces itself (I assume) on any value element, can i limit it to only `a` elements?
2. I work with java. with that I get the following error:
   `A '(' character or an element type is required in the declaration of element type "value".`

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

`#CDATA` is a non-existing keyword. It is not possible to declare an element to be of type `#CDATA`.

The `CDATA` keyword (without `#`) has two distinct uses:

1. In [attribute declarations in DTDs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-attribute-types).
2. In [CDATA sections](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-cdata-sect), which occur in XML document instances only (cannot be declared in DTDs).

To be clear: it is not possible to declare an element as a "cdata/CDATA/#CDATA" type. A CDATA section (`<![CDATA[...]]>`) is a convenience for XML authors. It is simply used in an XML document if needed. It is not something that is declared in a DTD.

See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12128273/407651.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. Is it possible to declare an element as cdata, so that I can simply fill the element's content with unique characters (&>!?) without actually writing `<![CDATA[....]]>`?

Comment: No, it is not possible to declare an element as "cdata" (or "CDATA"). A CDATA section is simply used in the XML document if needed. It cannot be declared in a DTD.